# Detox react-native run multiple e2e files

Tags: javascript, react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I started to do several test with detox (in my react native project) in one file and I was wondering if it was possible to do it in several files?

because when I tried in 2 different files, detox starts with the 2ND file and not the 1ST??

Here is my .detoxrc.json:

```
"testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "skipLegacyWorkersInjection": true,
  "apps": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.app",
      "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobileApp.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/mobileApp.xcworkspace -scheme mobileApp -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build"
    },
    "android": {
      "type": "android.apk",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd .."
    }
  },
  "devices": {
    "simulator": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 11"
      }
    },
    "emulator": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_3a_API_28"
      }
    }
```

my config.json:

```
{
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./init.ts"],
  "maxWorkers": 1,
  "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
  "testTimeout": 120000,
  "testRegex": "\\.e2e\\.ts$",
  "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
  "verbose": true
}
```

and my init.ts:

```
import { cleanup, init, device } from 'detox';

beforeAll(async () => {
  await init();
  await device.launchApp({ permissions: { photos: 'YES', camera: 'YES' } });
  await device.reloadReactNative();
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  await device.launchApp();
  // await device.reloadReactNative();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await cleanup();
});
```

If you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your config:

`setupFilesAfterEnv: ['PATH_TO_INIT_FILE']` (detox version 20)

or:

`setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: 'PATH_TO_INIT_FILE'` (old version)